# Get all worksheet names in plaintext from Excel with C# Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm using VS2010 + Office Interop 2007 to attempt to get a few specific spreadsheet names from an Excel spreadsheet with 5-6 pages.  All I am doing from there is saving those few spreadsheets I need in a tab delimited text file for further processing.  So for the three spreadsheet names I get, each one will have its own tab delimited text file.

I can save a file as tab delimited just fine through Interop, but that's assuming I know what the given page name is.  I have been informed that each page name will not follow a strict naming convention, but I can account for multiple names like "RCP", "rcp", "Recipient", etc when looking for a desired name.

My question is, can I get all spreadsheet page names in some sort of index so I may iterate through them and try to find the three names I need?  That would be so much nicer than trying to grab "RCP", "rcp", "Recipient" pages via a bajillion try/catches.

I'm close, because I can get the COUNT of pages in an Excel spreadsheet via the following:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();  // Creates a new Excel Application
excelApp.Visible = true;  // Makes Excel visible to the user.           
// The following code opens an existing workbook
string workbookPath = path;
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = null;
try
{
    excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0,
    false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true,
    false, 0, true, false, false);
}
catch
{
    //Create a new workbook if the existing workbook failed to open.
    excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
}
// The following gets the Worksheets collection
Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
Console.WriteLine(excelSheets.Count.ToString()); //dat count
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
foreach ( Worksheet worksheet in excelWorkbook.Worksheets )
{
   MessageBox.Show( worksheet.Name );
}
```

You could use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Worksheet> dict = new Dictionary<string, Worksheet>();
foreach ( Worksheet worksheet in excelWorkbook.Worksheets )
{
   dict.Add( worksheet.Name, worksheet );
}
// accessing the desired worksheet in the dictionary
MessageBox.Show( dict[ "Sheet1" ].Name );
```

Comment: Shrug.  Try it and let us know?

Comment: It does capture all sheets, hidden or not.  Thanks