# Excel/C# - Get worksheet id by name?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, worksheet

I currently have a worksheet with several sheets :
Sheet_Alpha | Sheet 2 | Sheet_Beta | Sheet 4 | Sheet 5 | Sheet_Delta

How I can recover them id according to their name? To be then able to select the sheet which I want with : `Worksheets.get_Item()`

Is it possible? I looked for a moment and I find nothing to do it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first transfer info about all the sheets of the workbook to a List as below

```
string name = "xxx";
List<Worksheet> lstSheet = new List<Worksheet>();
foreach (Worksheet ws in MyBook.Sheets)
{
    lstSheet.Add(ws);
}
```

And then access the target sheet by name as below

```
Worksheet wsToQuery = lstSheet.Find(a => a.Name.Contains(name));
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Nice approach ! You did it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at: [Get all worksheet names in plaintext from Excel with C# Interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788091/get-all-worksheet-names-in-plaintext-from-excel-with-c-sharp-interop/18788200#18788200)

```
foreach ( Worksheet worksheet in excelWorkbook.Worksheets )
{
   MessageBox.Show( worksheet.Name );
}
```

You could use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Worksheet> dict = new Dictionary<string, Worksheet>();
foreach ( Worksheet worksheet in excelWorkbook.Worksheets )
{
   dict.Add( worksheet.Name, worksheet );
}
// accessing the desired worksheet in the dictionary
MessageBox.Show( dict[ "Sheet1" ].Name );
```